# Lubuntu - can't connect to WiFi

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I am trying out Lubuntu. Before I install it, I need to connect to Wifi - how do I do so?

A screenshot of what I see is below:

[image]

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/a/566012/232364)